# Tax discount for item calculator

Tags: python, calculator, discount, tax

How do i make a code where user input if rhe item they want has tax and then discount and then they input the percent of discount and all these price are added to the total cost

Comment: Start by downloading Python and an IDE.

Answer (score -2):

it is an easy concept , it will be something like this:

```
earnings = int(input("Insert your earnings : "))
taxes = 0.20
if earnings < 10000:
    totTaxes = int(earnings * 0.20)
    salary = earnings - totTaxes
    print("Your Salary is ", salary)
    print("The taxes amount are : ", totTaxes)
```

i think you are new in python, u can copy and run this script on python idle , its a simple python scrpts IDE that executes the scripts
this is the link to download it for windows [LINK](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.4/python-3.10.4-amd64.exe).
Good luck!